# Change github repository for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

How do you change the git repository a rail app is pushed to? I know that this is possible because I did it a few weeks back.

Basically I have two very different versions of a app on my local machine. I would like the initial app to still point to the old repository. However, the new version needs to be placed in a completely separate repository.

When I run `git init` in `myapps/old_app/` it puts `Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/jamespollard/rails/old_repository/.git/`

AND

When I run `git init` in `myapps/new_app/` it puts `Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/jamespollard/rails/new_repository/.git/`

However, when I try and git push anything to the repository, it still goes to the old_repository.

### Updates

If I enter `$ git remote origin  set-url git@github.com:mygithub/myapp.git`
I get

```
error: Unknown subcommand: origin
usage: git remote [-v | --verbose]
    or: git remote add [-t <branch>] [-m <master>] [-f] [--mirror=<fetch|push>] <name> <url>
    or: git remote rename <old> <new>
    or: git remote rm <name>
    or: git remote set-head <name> (-a | -d | <branch>)
    or: git remote [-v | --verbose] show [-n] <name>
    or: git remote prune [-n | --dry-run] <name>
    or: git remote [-v | --verbose] update [-p | --prune] [(<group> | <remote>)...]
    or: git remote set-branches <name> [--add] <branch>...
    or: git remote set-url <name> <newurl> [<oldurl>]
    or: git remote set-url --add <name> <newurl>
    or: git remote set-url --delete <name> <url>
    -v, --verbose         be verbose; must be placed before a subcommand
```

If I enter `$ git remote set-url git@github.com:mygithub/myapp.git` I get the same error message as above (minus the origin error). In either case, if I run `git push origin master` it still pushes to the old repository. I've tried adding the new repository again with the same name, but I get a error (which i would expect) saying that it already exists.

Comment: A rails app doesn't "point" to a git repository FWIW.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a new repository in GitHub for you new app, if you haven't already. Make that new repository as origin to your new repository:

```
git remote add origin <github_url>
```

If the remote already exists, you might have to `git remote set-url origin <github_url>`

Now, push to the repo.

Comment: Thanks! The remote already exists. When I use the `git remote set-url` i just outputs info on how to use the remote set-url command. After I ran the command, should I be able to run the `git commit` and git `push commands` like I normally would? Or do I need to run something like `git remote push`?

Comment: @James did the set-url not work? Do `git remote add origin <github_url>` first. After it is set, you should be able to commit and push with `git push origin master` like normal

Comment: hey @manojlds, I have already set up the set-url using `git remote add origin <github_url>` a few weeks back. Now that I'm trying to update files, I'm failing to reconnect with the remote set-url. I've updated my original post with more details showing what I'm receiving when I try and use git remote origin set-url.

Comment: @James - I gave it as `git remote origin set-url <github_url>`. It should have been `git remote set-url origin <github_url>`. Updated the answer.

Comment: Hey Guys! What should really go into the gitignore of a rails app. I mean what should be ignored before committing a rails app to github

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a pretty similar situation few months ago.  On the new version of the app there is a .git folder (which was also copied along with all other files when you copied the app). Heroku needs the information from .git to see if anything has changed. So when it 'reinitialized', heroku thinks its the same app.

So here's what I did that resolved the problem.

- Copied the entire app folder.
- Changed app name wherever they appear (mostly in config folder, google it for a list)
- Chang secret.yml file (get a new key by rake secret) or secret token if older version
  of rails.

Most importantly, there should be a .git folder in your app folder (it maybe hidden).

- Delete that .git folder (it contains git info of the old app)
- Initialize a new git, git init
- and then commit and push.

Your new app should be a separate app now.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work if on heroku, worth a try:

```
git remote rm heroku
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:yourappname.git
```

or you can try this

1). open a terminal

2). Go to your_app_directory/.git/config

3). Once you open the config file then edit as follows:

Change

```
url = git@heroku.com:old_app_name.git
```

to

```
url = git@heroku.com:new_app_name.git
```

Obviously substituting your apps old name to its new name. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you take a peek at your `.git/config` file, you see / check that the url is still pointing to the old remote

```
[remote "origin"]
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
  url = <old_github_url>
```

so you wish to keep the old remote. let's call that `oldremote`.

First thing you can do is the rename the remote with :

```
git remote rename origin oldremote
```

Now you can add the new remote with :

```
git remote add origin <new_github_url>
```

From now on, pushing normally with just `git push` will push to the new remote. `git push oldremote SHA` to push to the old remote

remote reference : http://help.github.com/remotes/